# Embedding or copying locally interop?

Tags: c#, deployment, office-interop

I've run into a few troubles with the interop dlls.
When I use embed interop  in the references true, then the program functions, but if I say "don't embed instead copy locally" the dll isn't in the bin directory and thus the program says file not found on windows 8.

So my question is: is there any known reason for this and also what should be preferred for interop: embed or copy local?